# Radius of $n$-dimensional ellipsoid

Tags: geometry

Let $E=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : Ax \cdot x\leq1\}$ be an ellipsoid centered at $0$. $A$ is a $n \times n$ positive definite matrix. Let $x \in E$, and let $r(x)$ be the radius of ellipsoid passing through point $x$. How can we find $r(x)$? In $2$ dimensions this can be done, only I don't see how this can be generalized.

Answer (score 1):

A generic point on the ray through the origin and $x$ is given by $tx/|x|$, where $t$ is a positive number. Substitute that into the ellipsoid equation: $Ax\cdot x\ t^2/|x|^2=1$, to get: $r(x)=t=|x|/\sqrt{Ax\cdot x}$.